# grep - how to display another word instead of the matching of grep

Tags: shell

Given input like:

```
ID            VALUE
technique     lol
technology    case 
london        knife
ocean         sky
```

I'm currently using

```
grep -Eo '^[^ ]+' FILE | grep "tech"
```

for match every word which contain "tech" in the ID column.
In this case, it display :

```
 technique 
 technology
```

However does anyone can tell me how can I display the word from the second column regarding the word matching in the first column ?
For example how to display the word:

```
 lol
 case
```

(display the value instead the key)

Also, how can I display the key (as above) and the value separate by "=" like ? (without any spaces):

```
key=value
```

Thanks

Comment: This would be easier using another tool like awk -- is using grep a requirement?

Answer (score 3):

You can grep for lines starting with "tech" and then just display the second column. The exact format depends on how your input file columns are separated. If they are tab separated:

```
grep '^tech' FILE | cut -f 2
```

If they are space separated:

```
grep '^tech' FILE | tr -s ' ' $'\t' | cut -f 2
```

This "squeezes" repeated spaces and replaces them with a single tab character.

For your second question, you can use

```
sed -n '/^tech/ s/[[:space:]]\+/=/p' FILE
```

This means "don't print (`-n`); on lines matching `^tech`, make the substitution and print".

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk '$1 ~ "tech" {print $2}' < inputfile
```

or with key=value

```
awk '$1 ~ "tech" {print $1"="$2}' < inputfile
```

Comment: Thank you but before trying, could you tell me what does $1 and $2 corresponding to ?

Comment: @S7_0 *After* trying, you wouldn't have to ask ;)

Comment: Awk breaks its input into tokens (using whitespace as the delimiter be default).  These tokens are numbered, left-to-right, `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, ... etc.  You can think of them as column numbers.  (Also there is `$0` which is the whole input line.)

Comment: You don't need `< inputfile` just `awk '$1 ~ "tech" {print $1"="$2}' inputfile` is good enough.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, thanks.  I tend not to think of that option because I'm usually using awk in a pipeline.